# Loop with dates "don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate"

Tags: google-apps-script

My internet research was vain.
Getting the range of dates & comparing them with today's date. After running the **script #1** below I receive **Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.**, however when I run the **script #2** for a single value (not a loop), everything is fine.
How can I make the **script #1** work?
Thanks

**script #1**

```
    function abc() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var datA = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar').getDataRange().getValues();
var todayD = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'America/Los_Angeles', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
for (var i = 0; i < datA.length; i++){
  var mes = datA[i][0];
  var mes = Utilities.formatDate(mes,'America/Los_Angeles', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
   if (mes == todayD) {
    Logger.log("yes");}
}  
Logger.log(mes)
}
```

**script #2**

```
function missingDLemail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var datA = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar').getDataRange().getValues();
var todayD = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'America/Los_Angeles', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
// for (var i = 0; i < datA.length; i++){
  var mes = datA[6][0];
  var mes = Utilities.formatDate(mes,'America/Los_Angeles', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
   if (mes == todayD) {
    Logger.log("yes");}
// }  
Logger.log(mes)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since script #2 works, the value in cell `A7`, i.e., `datA[6][0]`, must be a date.

The fact that script #1 throws an error tells that at least one other value in column `A` is not a date. The error message you quote suggests that the problematic value is a text string — perhaps it looks like a date, but it is actually not a date.

Look for values like `2/30/2021`, and date formats that are invalid in your spreadsheet locale. For example, `31/12/2021` would be invalid in the United States locale, and `12/31/2021` would be invalid in the United Kingdom locale. You can find whether a value is a date or a text string that looks like a date with the `isnumber()` spreadsheet function.

In Apps Script, you can test whether a value is a date with this statement as the first thing in the `for` loop:

```
  var mes = datA[i][0];
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(mes) !== '[object Date]') {
    Logger.log('The value "' + String(mes) + '" is not a date.');
    continue;
  }
```

Comment: True :) , the solution for this specific problem is to run from i=1, i.e. for (var i = 1; i < datA.length; i++) before the first row is the heading.